# PoundCake plugin in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to use poundcake plugin in cakephp 1.2 . But I get the following error
"Fatal error: Call to undefined method App::path() in C:\wamp\www\OnlineTickets\app\plugins\bcp\controllers\components\layouts.php on line 25"

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you are trying to use is not compatible with CakePHP 1.2 since `App::path()` function only exists in version 1.3 and above.